# Can't Understand this MySQL Connection String

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-6

I'm troubleshooting a WPF C# App for one of our clients.

The App connects to a MySQL Database. However, the connection string is in the form of 'metadata' with an .ssdl and .msl file

What is this Metadata thing, ssdl and msl file?

```
<add name="NFMEntity" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TrendData.csdl|res://*/TrendData.ssdl|res://*/TrendData.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=127.0.0.1;user id=mmm;password=mmmmmm;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=nfm&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: No idea but this might help http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

The metadata section with .csdl, .ssdl, and .msl are used by EF and they contain different layers of the model you describe via EF. This section is not part of the database connection string.

[Exploring how the Entity Data Model (EDM) Generates Code and Executes Queries – Entity Framework 4.0](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=603) blog post provides a high level description of these layers:

> We know that Entity Framework maps database tables to objects. This is
>   done in 3 different layers:
>
> Logical Layer: The Logical Layer also called Storage Layer is defined
>   by the Store Schema Definition Language (SSDL) and defines the
>   structure of the tables and relations between them.
>
> Conceptual Layer: The Conceptual Layer is defined by the Conceptual
>   Schema Definition Language (CSDL) and defined .NET classes.
>
> Mapping Layer: The Mapping Layer is defined by Mapping Specification
>   Language (MSL) and connects the entity type definition from the CSDL
>   to the metadata defined in the SSDL, hence the name C-S mapping. So
>   the mapping is essentially from .NET classes to the table structure
>   and its relations.
>
> At runtime, this .edmx is split into these three different files
>   (.ssdl, .csdl and .msl).